# Difference between "human" and "human being"

Tags: differences

My high school teacher told me that "human" is not interchangeable with "human being" in certain contexts.  But he did not really give any clear examples.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone can clearly define the difference and provide some examples.

Comment: Look up what various dictionaries claim to be the adjectival usage of 'human'. *'Human being frailty.' *'The milk of human being kindness.' *'Human being endeavour.'

Answer (score 2):

"Human" can be used as an adjective, or a noun.  The noun form means the same as "human being".

"human being" is not an adjective, so we can't use it in place of "human" when we're using human as an adjective.

For example:

> "I'm only human" -> adjective
>
> "I'm only a human" -> noun

So, we can say "I'm only a human being", but **not** "I'm only human being", for example.